# Angular 10, how to get a "date" from a formControl

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I have a formControl as a date

```
formGroup = fb.group({data_cadastro, [new Date()]...
```

that is mapped to  primeng

```
 <p-calendar formControlName="data_cadstro">.....
```

Howcan I get the iso string from that formControl?

```
  this.formGroup.control['data_cadastro'].value ?
```

Basically I need to get the Date object.

Answer (score 0):

In the `PrimeNG` Calendar, the value type is `date` by default, and you can change it using `dataType` input which takes `date` or `string`.

So in your case if you're using the default `dataType`, then the value type of the `form-control` is `date`, and you can get it like the following:

```js
const data_cadastro = this.formGroup.control['data_cadastro'].value as Date;
```

And if you're using the `string` `dataType` you can get it like the following:

```js
const data_cadastro = new Date(this.formGroup.control['data_cadastro'].value);
```